# Prometheus vs ElasticSearch. Which is better for container and server monitoring?

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, prometheus

ElasticSearch is a document store and more of a search engine, I think ElasticSearch is not good choice for monitoring high dimensional data as it consumes lot of resources. On the other hand prometheus is a TSDB which is designed for capturing high dimensional data.

Anyone experienced in this please let me know what's the best tool to go with for container and server monitoring.

Comment: We use ELK for monitoring and it does a good job. It really likely depends on what exactly you're trying to do and what exactly you mean by "high dimensional."

Comment: Indeed, for truly highly dimensional data you need an event logging solution suck as ELK. For container and server monitoring you want a metrics solution like Prometheus.

Comment: prometheus can give me the labels for the metrics captured. For ex: container_cpu_usage_total{image="xyz", cpu="cpu01", label1="somevalue"}. Whatever is in the flower brackets is what I mean by dimensional. ELasticSearch won't give me this.

Comment: "ELK" is the acronym for three open source projects: Elasticsearch, Logstash, and Kibana. Elasticsearch is a search and analytics engine

Answer (score 79, accepted):

ELK is a general-purpose no-sql stack that *can* be used for monitoring. We've successfully deployed one on production and used it for some aspects of our monitoring system. You can ship metrics into it (if you wish) and use it to monitor them, but its not specifically designed to do that. Nor does the non-commercial version (version 7.9) come with an alerting system - you'll need to setup another component for that (like Sensu) or pay for ES commercial license.

Prometheus, on the other hand, is designed to be used for monitoring. And along with its metric-gathering clients (or other 3rd party clients like [Telegraf](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf) and its service discovery options (like consul) and its alert-manager is just the right tool for this job.

Ultimately, both solutions can work, but in my opinion Elasticsearch will require more work and more upkeep (we found that ES clusters are a pain to maintain - but that depends on the amount of data you'll have).

Comment: completely agree with you.

Answer (score 16):

I am using openshift and we are running both tool and both have different job. aggregating all the logging and shipping to elastic search for ease of browsing all the logging and similar things.

our prometheus use is mainly for metrics either for the nodes or the pods and definitely grafana makes a great interface to view all of prometheus metrics for sure.

Comment: yeah ELK is mainly log analysis system.

Answer (score -11):

Agree that it depends on what you mean by "high dimensional" and for container and server monitoring. You could use some opensource monitoring solution, I've tried Pandora FMS and they offer several options for high environments and distributed architectures, server monitoring is mostly agent based tho, but I feel it has a lot of potential.